# Why javascript return object place of true or false

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to get the return value (true or false) of the fonction but the result is only an circular object, so I can't use this function.
The code used:

```
function check_session(data) {
    var sql_read_req="SELECT * FROM "+appconfig['bdd_table']+" WHERE  `"+appconfig['bdd_pseudo']+"`="+mySqlRead.escape(data.name)+" AND `"+appconfig['bdd_session_hash']+"`="+mySqlRead.escape(data.session)+" AND `"+appconfig['bdd_is_valide']+"`=1";
    mySqlRead.query(sql_read_req, function (err, result){
            if((result)&&(result.length!=0)){
                console.log('session ok: '+result);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
    });
}
```

So `check_session(data)` return Object.
I can't serialize the result because it's a circular object.

Where is the error?

Comment: the true false occurs in a callback function

Comment: It shouldn't return anything without a `return` statement in the function itself, did you mean to remove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `return` before `mySqlRead.query`, the return value should probably come from the callback, not from the invocation.

Also, you will want to add a callback argument to `check_session` which you should call from within the `mySqlRead.query` callback, e.g.

```
function check_session(data, cb) {
  mySqlRead.query(sql_read_req, function(err, result) {
    return cb(result && result.length);
  });
}

check_session(SOME_DATA, function(itWorked) {
  console.log('It worked?', itWorked);
});
```

Comment: I remove the `return` before `mySqlRead.query` but no the result of call `check_session(data)`is undefined.
I don't see why I should use a callback for just return true or false.
is it because with the function in query I modify the comportment of the query ?
If I introduce a callback fonction how to call the function ?

Comment: You use a callback because javascript is asynchronus, and a query to the database does not immediately produce your answer.  You may do more research to see if the library you used provides a *synchronous* query, but I highly doubt that's the case.  If you're not used to writing asychronous code, either get used to it or get used to using Promises, because this will *always* be a problem for you if you don't understand why a lot of node functions require a callback.

Comment: You can call it like in my example. The thing is that the query is most likely executed async, meaning that it will complete sometime in the future; we do not know when. That is why we use callbacks or promises, to wait until the execution has happened and then do something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
For me the function should not stop this execution before all function included do the same.
Of course the usage of a callback is beautifull.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be 100% sure without the rest of your code, but mySqlRead.query is most likely returning a promise ([doc about promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)).

When you call check_session(), you shouldn't bother about the return result (unless you want to do something when mySqlRead.query finishes, like chaining promises)

In your case, you probably want:

```
check_session(data).then(function(result){
  console.log("The result is", result ,"!");
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the `console.log` is write for debug only.
I realy whant to return true or false only.

Comment: Well instead of console.log, you can put whatever you want to do with the "true" or "false" result. ```function``` in my example is the same as a callback. You should really click the link and learn about promises ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you are looking for, but `check_session(data)` does not return a value. `check_session(data)` actually finishes its execution before the anonymous function `function(err, result)` you pass to `mySqlRead` is called. In your code the anonymous function is returning a result, but nothing is being done with that.

Probably what you want to do is pass in a call back to `check_session(data)` and then call that with a true or false parameter

eg

```
function respondToRead(success){
    if(success) ...
    else ...
}

function check_session(data, callback) {
    var sql_read_req="SELECT * FROM "+appconfig['bdd_table']+" WHERE `"+appconfig['bdd_pseudo']+"`="+mySqlRead.escape(data.name)+" AND `"+appconfig['bdd_session_hash']+"`="+mySqlRead.escape(data.session)+" AND `"+appconfig['bdd_is_valide']+"`=1";
mySqlRead.query(sql_read_req, function (err, result){
        if((result)&&(result.length!=0)){
            console.log('session ok: '+result);
            callback(true);
        }
        else {
            callback(false);
        }
});
```

}